# swi-prolog progam "no change given" not quite returning denominations properly

Tags: prolog

If I decomment the 'abort' in line 3, the program produces an approximation of the required output on the screen eg.:

```
?- biggest_denom(37,P).
Pay with 25 ; remainder =12
Pay with 10 ; remainder =2
Pay with 1 ; remainder =1
Pay with 1 ; remainder =0
Finish
% Execution Aborted
?-
```

However, I want the 'purer' return-solutions-when-hit-semicolon or return-as-list variations. ("trace." didn't seem to provide any clues).

The best I can get (with 'abort' in line 3 not decommented), is:

```
?- biggest_denom(13,P).
Pay with 10 ; remainder =3
Pay with 1 ; remainder =2
Pay with 1 ; remainder =1
Pay with 1 ; remainder =0
Finish
P = 10 ;
Pay with 5 ; remainder =8
Pay with 5 ; remainder =3
Pay with 1 ; remainder =2
Pay with 1 ; remainder =1
Pay with 1 ; remainder =0
Finish
P = 5 ;
Pay with 1 ; remainder =7
Pay with 5 ; remainder =2
Pay with 1 ; remainder =1
Pay with 1 ; remainder =0
Finish
P = 5 ;
Pay with 1 ; remainder =6
Pay with 5 ; remainder =1
Pay with 1 ; remainder =0
Finish
P = 5 ;
Pay with 1 ; remainder =5
Pay with 5 ; remainder =0
Finish
P = 5 ;
Pay with 1 ; remainder =4
Pay with 1 ; remainder =3
Pay with 1 ; remainder =2
Pay with 1 ; remainder =1
Pay with 1 ; remainder =0
Finish
P = 5        %IT GOES ON AND ON LIKE THIS!! XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Here is my code:

```
%XXXXXXXXXXXXX no change given XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  
accept([100,50,25,10,5,1]). %pre-sorted (listing from big to small)

biggest_denom( 0 , _ ) :- writeln('Finish'). %,abort. %please STOP!!! horrible!
biggest_denom( N , D ) :-
  N \= 0  ,
  accept(X)  ,
  member(D,X) ,
  D =< N ,
  Remainder is N-D ,
  write('Pay with ') ,
  write(D) ,
  write(' ; remainder =') ,
  writeln(Remainder) ,
  %Remainder \= 0 , %gives more output, for some reason, not less
  biggest_denom(Remainder,D2)
  .

pay( N ) :- %print list of denoms which adds up to N ; will use findall
  writeln('not yet implemented') .
```

Any advice would be v much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should let the top level do the writing for you. And you could also get rid of the list in `accept/1` and put them as facts.

```
accept(100).
accept(50).
accept(25).
accept(10).
accept(5).
accept(1).

return_change(N, C) :- integer(N), N > 0,
    return_change_1(N, C).

return_change_1(0, []) :- !.
return_change_1(N, [X-R|Change]) :-
    accept(X),
    X =< N,
    R is N - X,
    return_change_1(R, Change).
```

This is actually all you need to do.

```
?- return_change(37, C), !.
C = [25-12, 10-2, 1-1, 1-0].
```

Or, if you insist on the output:

```
?- return_change(37, C), !, forall(member(P-R, C), format("Pay with ~d ; remainder ~d~n", [P, R])).
Pay with 25 ; remainder 12
Pay with 10 ; remainder 2
Pay with 1 ; remainder 1
Pay with 1 ; remainder 0
C = [25-12, 10-2, 1-1, 1-0].
```

Remove the cut in the query to get more solutions.

As @mat points out, the call `foo, !` can be expressed more elegantly using the predicate `once/1`, like this: `once(foo)`

Comment: @mat Yes, and this was on purpose. The wrong thing was to change the name of the predicate.

Comment: Yes, there are similar versions of this program asking for all possible manners of paying or returning change, but today I was only after that one most obvious solution, which, I think, is what Boris' code appears to do always. Thanks to all, esp. to Boris!!!

Comment: `once/1` is an elegant alternative for committing to the first solution.